# Ubuntu 20.04 super key doesn't work with different language input

Tags: ubuntu, gnome3, keyboard-layout, language

When I have my typing language set to anything other than English, <kbd>Super</kbd> key doesn't work. I can't use any keyboard shortcut that contains <kbd>Super</kbd> in it, and I also can't press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd> every time as I got more than two input languages.

I think that before I updated the distribution version, it worked normally, as I haven't noticed this problem ever before.

Answer (score 3):

This is a known and recently fixed bug: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/issues/1144. It should be fixed in Ubuntu once they update mutter to 3.36.2.